# Выбор массива из mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Имеется коллекция с документами вида. Используя mongoose вытащить объект из массива categories, который соответствует `_id: ObjectId("5a27d2ee8593b81794eaa626")` и `categories._id: ObjectId("5a29087faa42ea1862dd8ebe")`. Причем получить мне нужно конкретный объект из массива categories, а не конкретный документ. Как это реализовать?
Получить я должен:

```
"categories" : [ 
                    {
                        "id_category" : ObjectId("5a2563fa4b19cd464b2a08e1"),
                        "title" : "Зарплата",
                        "def_value" : 2000,
                        "value" : 179,
                        "types" : "income",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5a29087faa42ea1862dd8ebe")
                    }, 
 ]
```

Исходная коллекция:

```
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a27d2ee8593b81794eaa626"),
            "date" : ISODate("2017-11-30T21:00:00.000Z"),
            "user" : ObjectId("5a25609073f01345e7de44f1"),
            "categories" : [ 
                {
                    "id_category" : ObjectId("5a2563fa4b19cd464b2a08e1"),
                    "title" : "Зарплата",
                    "def_value" : 2000,
                    "value" : 179,
                    "types" : "income",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5a29087faa42ea1862dd8ebe")
                }, 
                {
                    "id_category" : ObjectId("5a2907b9aa42ea1862dd8eb2"),
                    "title" : "Фриланс",
                    "def_value" : 200,
                    "value" : 200,
                    "types" : "income",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5a29087faa42ea1862dd8ebd")
                }, 
                {
                    "id_category" : ObjectId("5a29073aaa42ea1862dd8eb1"),
                    "title" : "Продукты",
                    "def_value" : 500,
                    "value" : 179,
                    "types" : "outcome",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5a29087faa42ea1862dd8ebc")
                }, 
                {
                    "id_category" : ObjectId("5a25669f4c5a3f46a3f7379a"),
                    "title" : "Хозтовары",
                    "def_value" : 20,
                    "value" : 12,
                    "types" : "outcome",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5a29087faa42ea1862dd8ebb")
                }
            ],
            "__v" : 4
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить данные смог так:

```
db.budgets.find({"_id": ObjectId("5a27d2ee8593b81794eaa626")}, { "categories": { $elemMatch: { "_id": ObjectId("5a29087faa42ea1862dd8ebb") } } })
```